# Laravel, AWS S3 "Access Denied" Private Access

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3

I created an S3 bucket and can upload to it. I can view the upload programmatically in Laravel as long as my S3 bucket is fully public. Once I make it private, I get an "Access Denied" error. I've created a User, given that user AmazonS3FullAccess permission and included the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID & AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY into .env. I followed this guide: https://dev.to/aschmelyun/getting-started-with-amazon-s3-storage-in-laravel-5b6d. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Does it still store accordingly or is it when trying to view that you get the error ?
Have you taken a look at
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#file-urls

You should be using something like

```
Storage::url($customer->file-path-name);
```

By the way try avoiding hyphen separated name. Either go camelCase or snake_case ... hyphen are typically reserved for file names(the actual file, not the reference in your DB)

Comment: I can store. I get the error when trying to view. I also get the same error when trying to view the upload while signed in as the root user in the S3 console.

Comment: I ran the list-buckets & list-objects AWS CLI commands to verify the canonical IDs match.

Comment: This is how I am attempting to access the uploads: <a href="{{'https://my-bucket-name.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/'. $customer->file-path-name}}" target="_blank"><span >View File</span></a>. Would this approach be a problem? It works as long as the bucket is public but when the bucket is private, storing the object works but I get "Access Denied" when trying to view.